# Mandatory member function arguments - to much expectations from Python compiler and/or PyDev

Tags: python, pydev

I've created the class `CustomErr` (inherits from Python's `Exception`) long time ago and I'm using it on a few hundred places in code. It has a member method which is declared with `def logErr(self)`.

After some time I found that this function should have mandatory keyword argument **logger**, so I've changed declaration of the function to `def logErr(self, *, logger)`.

After this change I've expected a few hundred compiler errors, or at least warnings (so it will be easy for me to make needed changes), but it didn't happen - there is not a single error reported. I only get runtime exception when this function is called.

Did I expect too much from Python compiler and/or my working IDE (I'm using Eclipse with PyDev 8.1, Python 3.8.7)?

Do I need a Python linter ?

Comment: Python is not a compiled language. Such errors will happen at runtime, since even the method can be modified or replaced at any time.

Comment: @KlausD. But you would normally expect an IDE to warn about things like this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! About your question: it seems non-answerable directly. A. Yes. You expect from python behaviour of static typing language. B. "Do I need linter?" - it's for you to decide and which one and which settings. We use 3 of them in the same time: flake8 for cicd, pylint for manual check and mypy to test signatures

Comment: Of external tools, mypy and pyright should be able to see that error. The PyCharm IDE certainly can. The Python interpreter doesn't care, as Klaus said.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I came to Python from C++ and Java, so my expectations were high. I'll probably try with pylint (for mypy it is too late).

Answer (score 0):

`PyDev` by default doesn't really provide this checking -- it does have code-analysis builtin, but it focuses on being very fast and on having very few false positives and it doesn't really delve in the type-checking territory.

In `PyDev` the recommended way to work with this is through an external linter or type-checker.

`PyDev` has integrations with `Flake8`, `Mypy` and `PyLint` (the related configuration in the preferences is under `PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis > Flake8/Mypy/PyLint`).

If you're using type hints in your code, enabling `Mypy` is probably a no-brainer and actually required to make use of such typing for code analysis in PyDev... out of the box PyDev will use that info for code-completion, but there aren't plans to add it for code analysis as I'm a bit worried about duplicating what's already available in `Mypy` anyways and I don't see much positives in having yet another type checker.

`PyLint` may also be interesting as it does get some interesting errors (but in my experience it usually also has a higher false positive ratio, so, it may need to be tweaked a bit more) -- if you don't use type-hints (and thus wouldn't really get much from `Mypy`), I think that using `PyLint` is interesting as it does try to cover more ground than PyDev.

As a note, if you're not using type-checking/`MyPy`, what you want is probably not achievable with 100% certainty by any tool because it's difficult to find out that something as `parameter.logErr` means the `logErr` in your `CustomErr` and not really some other `logErr` somewhere else (because discovering that the type of `parameter` is `CustomErr` is really hard).

p.s.: automatically running the type-checker/linter is done for each file as you save it, but you can also run it for the whole project by right-clicking a project/file and then selecting `PyDev > Code Analysis`.